# Numpy.dot hang my program, i assume that is memory problem

Tags: numpy

I have two numpy array: A shape(512,) and B (3000,512). One function call
C = np.dot(B,A) and my program hang without any error out.
My python 3.7.3 and numpy 1.16.2.

But that code run good if i call c = np.dot(B,A) manual with suitable input or the length of B around 50

I don't know what difference between 2 ways of call.

Comment: Just guessing, what about using A shape (1, 512)

Comment: @JohnZwinck My free RAM is 36GB and CPU(s) 16, i am sure that it can consume all. Should know that if i run that code manually it take 2ms. dtype = float32

Comment: @Tarik more suitable shape for A is (512,1) but program still hang with program call

Comment: I think the error is somewhere in the code you aren't showing us.

Comment: Hi @FirefoxMetzger i checked by np.show_config(), it show me something like "HAVE_CBLAS" and pid look like: pid 89's current affinity mask: ffff
pid 89's new affinity mask: ff
0. What those are mean?

Comment: Tell us more about `B` (in the problem case).  `dtype`?  `type`? (is it really a numpy array)?  Is your program using anything besides `numpy`?  The (3000,512) and (512,) shapes are not, normally, a problem, even on a modest computer.  Does `B.dot(A)` run any better?

Comment: Hi @hpaulj i did try B.dot(A) before post this question, so the result similar to np.dot(B,A), their dtype=np.float32 and their type <class np.ndarray>, code work quite good on manual case so that it can't be a syntax error.

Comment: I don't suspect syntax.  I'm wondering whether `B` is something unusual.  For example if `B` is a sparse matrix, `B.dot(A)` is right, `np.dot(B,A)` is wrong.

Comment: @hpaulj on my code, B is assigned to numpy after had loaded from database, on manual running case both A.dot(A) and np.dot(B,A) given same results. Did i misunderstand your point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. This because of proceed memory limit. My program when running taking 20GB of RAM and when numpy need more memory for it's working the system hanged without a any error or warning, but when i call my that function manually, it called another process and got more RAM for it's work.

Comment: I still find it curious that it requires what I would qualify as a crazy amount of memory: 20GB. 3000 x 512 x 8 = 12,288,000 bytes. With the code I provided, things were instantaneous. Even with 1,000,000 rows, the allocated RAM only hit around 5GB.

Answer (score 0):

When A comes first, you need to use the transpose of B. Interestingly, I did not have to change the shape of A. This does not seem to be consistent to me, but it works.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([i for i in range(512)])
B = np.random.rand(3000, 512)

C1 = B.dot(A)      # 3000 rows, 512 

B = B.transpose()      # 512 rows, 3,000 columns
C2 = A.dot(B)
C2 = C2.transpose()    # 3,000 rows, 512 columns

print(np.all(np.equal(C1, C2))) # Verify that the result is the same
```

Comment: Thank for your reply @Tarik. But my input worked good with B.dot(A) or np.dot(B,A)